# Customize getRouteKeyName() Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Location` model. The problem is that in my country exists locations of all levels with same name. So, I want to separate them by a custom field created from  `name` + `-` + `id`.

Is there a way of rewriting something like

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

In something like that :

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name' . '-' . 'id';
}
```

Meaning, I can access the route by `/washington-24` , even this column don't exists?

Comment: why not use a package for that [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)

Comment: Something like an [accessor/mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)?

Comment: @kerbholz can I use accessor/mutator as a value that is used in route model binding?